# Too few servers in Battlefield 2?

Tags: battlefield-2

I recently tried battlefield 2 on my friend house and i loved it, I know it's pretty old but i had never played it before. The thing is, he has a pirated version, but I prefer to have my game collection on steam with original copies, so when I got home I bought it.

But in my version, when i go to "internet servers" list on multiplayer, the list have like 40 servers or so, and i remember seeing the server list on my friend's pirated copy, he had much more, like hundreds.

I tried removing all the filters (even "same version only") and still my servers list (and players) is pretty small compared to the pirated version I tried.

Is there anything i can update or change to get more servers? If someone has an original copy could you check how many servers you get and let me know to compare?

Comment: Can't even play on the few populated servers I get since they show >250 ping and PB kicks me everytime (I'm on a 12MB connection and have 50-100 ping on most games), and yes I closed all other programs and even steam in-game overlay. Oh well, what can I say, EA you got me again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess is that the Steam version and the old version (which he likely has since pirated games can't access the Steam service) don't have access to the same servers.

I'm not sure if Steam uses Gamespy for their multiplayer servers for Battlefield 2 but I'm almost positive that's what Battlefield 2, 1942, and 2142 used for multiplayer.

It's also worth noting that most times you deal with pirated games, they usually aren't connected to official servers for obvious reasons.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you know if these servers legit (not pirated versions) http://www.gametracker.com/search/bf2/ ? Because there are tons of servers there that doesn't show up on my in-game servers list. I guess on steam I have the latest version since i have it set on "high priority - always update" and it didn't ask me to update. I will see if i can get my hands on a legit non-steam copy and use the cd-key that steam gave me, maybe that will show more servers.

Comment: No problem Mark!  My best guess is that it's just a Steam vs Original thing.  The game is old enough to where there are probably no more "official" servers up anyway so likely what's going on is that Steam and the original game connect to different servers.  I can look in to it more when I'm home from work but that's the best I currently have without loading up both different versions of the game at home.  Hope it helps!

Comment: It could also be filtering by latency in Steam - showing only servers that are at a reasonable latency and excluding the really laggy ones or ones that are in different regions.  There might even be an in-game setting to change that but I haven't loaded the game up in years so I can't say for 100%, again, without loading the games up.

Comment: I uninstalled the game from steam and activated it on origin (had to do it from https://activate.ea.com/gameactivation.do because origin client said the key was invalid), now I can see about 500 servers. The ping problem seems to be my router, if I connect without it it works much better, still have to investigate why and if it can be fixed. Anyway thanks a lot for your time @Mkalafut.